# Using namespace on Symfony2 controller

Tags: symfony, php

I am pretty new on symfony2 (just reading its own pdf book) and I am curious that is it must to use namespace name as `namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Controller;`?

It is too long name and can I make it shorter with any other name or do I need to follow the directory path convention to name the namespace of the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to match the directory structure. You can view the namespace standard here:

https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md